# How to generate in a matlab script correlation plots?

Tags: signal-processing, time-series, matlab, correlation

I've been using Matlab's time series toolbox [tstool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tstool.html) to calculate the correlation between two time series, this works perfectly and gives me very informative graphs.

What I need to do is generate such correlation plots for a larger number of vectors, thus from within a script, I've read that `tstool` uses the `xcorr` function but I haven't found how to use it to produce results similar to tstool's.

Is there a way to look at the script wchich generates the correlation plot in the tstool GUI?

Or a way to call ts tools from a script something like:

```
ts = new tstool;
ts.corrplot(A,B)
```

Or some other way to produce tstool like correlation graphs, I'm interested in the lag scale especialy, in a script?

Comment: I don't see any obvious way, I guess you could try by exploring the code: `edit tstool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/time-series-tools.html#brenq06-46):

> **Cross-Correlation Algorithm**:  When computing the cross-correlation of
>   two vector-valued time series x and y, Time Series Tools uses an
>   algorithm that is functionally equivalent to calling the Signal
>   Processing Toolbox™ `xcorr` function from with the 'biased' option,
>   after the time series means have been removed. Unlike xcorr, however,
>   the cross-correlation estimate in Time Series Tools also works for
>   matrix-valued time series X and Y, where it computes the
>   cross-correlation of X(:,i) against Y(:,j) for all combinations of
>   columns i and j. Note that Time Series Tools do not actually use the
>   xcorr code, but rather a simplified version which works under these
>   restricted assumptions.

This should work:

```
%# random signal
y1 = cumsum(rand(1000,1)-0.5);

%# autocorrelation
maxlag = length(y1);   %# set a max lag value here
[c,lags] = xcorr(detrend(y1), maxlag, 'biased');

%# plot
plot(lags,c), xlabel('lags'), ylabel('autocorrelation')
```

[image: autocorrelation]

Note that the result might be a bit different from timeseries objects plots (depending on the time units used)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not interested in autocorrelation per say but I think I can adapt this code for the correlation between two vector.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

You could use [`plotmatrix()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/plotmatrix.html):

[image]

or, if you have the Econometrics Toolbox, [`corrplot()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/econ/corrplot.html):

[image]

Comment: I'll definitely use corrplot.